# Use array variable in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

```
A=(aaa bbb ccc)    
cat abc.txt | awk '{ print $1, ${A[$1]} }'
```

I want to index an array element based on the $1, but the code above is not correct in awk syntax. Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to be hard-coding the `A` array, you can just initialize it in `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{A[0]="aaa";A[1]="bbb"}{ print $1, A[$1] }' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't index a `bash` array using a value generated inside `awk`, even if you weren't using single quotes (thereby preventing `bash` from doing any substitution).  You could pass the array in, though.

```
A=(aaa bbb ccc)
awk -v a="${A[*]}" 'BEGIN {split(a, A, / /)}
                     {print $1, A[$1] }' <abc.txt
```

Because of the split function inside awk, the elements of `A` may not contain spaces or newlines.  If you need to do anything more interesting, set the array inside of `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN {a[1] = "foo bar"  # sadly, there is no way to set an array all
            a[2] = "baz"    } #   at once without abusing split() as above
           {print $1, a[$1] }' <abc.txt
```

(Clarification:  `bash` substitutes variables *before* invoking the program whose argument you're substituting, so by the time you have `$1` in `awk` it's far too late to ask `bash` to use it to substitute a particular element of `A`.)

Comment: It's a typo.  Thanks for telling me, I've fixed it.

Comment: @kurumi: Huh?  That was replacing the "useless use of `cat`".

Comment: @geekosaur, `awk` takes in an input file. `awk '{}' filename`

Comment: @kurumi Point, but 6 on one/half dozen on the other.  If anything, redirection is slightly faster.  Either is better than `cat file |`, though.

Comment: AWK will accept a filename as an argument without the need to redirect it using `<` as kurumi pointed out. While `awk '{...}' A=foo filename will work, the form that you have, `awk A=foo '{...}' filename` will not. You can, however, do `awk -v "A=foo" '{...}' filename`.

Comment: How could redirection be faster? The shell has the added burden of setting it up and AWK *still* has to open the input.

Comment: @geekosaur, i am curious, did you actually benchmark whether redirection is faster than just passing in a file argument? If you have and it proves that redirection is faster, I will change all my scripts to use redirection. :)

Comment: @kurumi: you're only going to notice a difference in microseconds, and it'll be swamped by process startup time.  @Dennis: `stdin` is already open, and what setup is needed for it (associating a `(FILE *)` with it) is going to be done by `crt0` whether or not `awk` then goes ahead and opens a different file.  But the more significant difference (to the extent that it matters) is that `awk` sets up various things when you open a file argument that are defaulted when you use `stdin`; as a result, it's a little (as above, only by microseconds) faster to let the shell do it and pass it as `stdin`.

Comment: BTW, I'm a little surprised that that's a bikeshed; when it comes down to it, it's personal preference more than anything else.

Comment: @geekosaur, on my system, redirection is always slower. ;)

Comment: It's not just personal preference, there are technical differences between the 2 approaches. If you use input redirection, for example, then awk cannot populate the FILENAME variable so within your awk script you don't have access to the name of the input file. The benefits to using redirection come in when there's a failure to open the file and other things (performance is NOT a differentiator) but they aren't worthwhile IMHO in light of losing FILENAME. Some people at comp.unix.shell NG could provide details and perhaps argue otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your awk program within single quotes cannot see the shell environment variable A.  In general, you can get a little shell substitution to work if you use double quotes instead of single quotes, but that is done by the shell, before awk is invoked.  Overall, it is heavy sledding to try to combine shell and awk this way.  If possible, I would take kurumi's approach of using an awk array.

Single quotes: an impenetrable veil.
Double quotes: generally too much travail.
So pick your poison: shell or awk.
Otherwise: your code may balk.

Answer (score 2):

You can also print each element of the array on separate line with printf and pipe it to awk. This code will simply print bash array (bash_arr) from awk:

```
bash_arr=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
printf '%s\n' "${bash_arr[@]}" | 
    awk '    { awk_arr[NR] = $0 }
         END {
             for (key in awk_arr) {
                 print awk_arr[key]
             }
         }'
```