# How to initialize an array of arrays in awk?

Tags: arrays, awk, initialization

Is it possible to initialize an array like this in AWK ?

```
Colors[1] = ("Red", "Green", "Blue")
Colors[2] = ("Yellow", "Cyan", "Purple")
```

And then to have a two dimensional array where Colors[2,3]="Purple".

---

From [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400228/use-array-variable-in-awk) I understand that it's not possible ( "sadly, there is no way to set an array all at once without abusing split()" ). Anyways I want to be 100% sure and I'm sure that there are others with the same question.

I am looking for the easiest method to initialize arrays like the one above, will be nice to have it well written.

Comment: `awk` "arrays" are associative maps rather than indexed arrays with sizes and there is no notion of a multi-dimensional array (though you can fake it by using strings with, say, '_' as a separator for the index), possible there is a better way...

Comment: awk (at least gawk) does have a semblance of multi-dimensional arrays. When you construct a key with a comma, the comma is replaced by the contents of the `SUBSEP` variable. Example: `gawk 'BEGIN {x[1,1]=1; for (i in x) printf "%s\n", i}' | xxd -g1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.
Anyways, for those who want to initialize unidimensional arrays, here is an example:

```
SColors = "Red_Green_Blue"
split(SColors, Colors, "_")
print Colors[1] " - " Colors[2] " - " Colors[3]
```

Comment: You asked a question about init-ing multi-dimensional arrays, got good answers to your question, but posted your own answer to a different question and accepted that. Anyone else see anything wrong with that? Anyway, the correct answer is [@Steve's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14064658/1745001).

Answer (score 19):

If you have `GNU awk`, you can use a [true multidimensional array](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html#Arrays-of-Arrays). Although this answer uses the `split()` function, it most certainly doesn't abuse it. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {

    x=SUBSEP

    a="Red" x "Green" x "Blue"
    b="Yellow" x "Cyan" x "Purple"

    Colors[1][0] = ""
    Colors[2][0] = ""

    split(a, Colors[1], x)
    split(b, Colors[2], x)

    print Colors[2][3]
}
```

Results:

```
Purple
```

Comment: That's the right answer but you've made it more complicated than it has to be which is IMHO obfuscating the fact that all you need is `{ Colors[1][0]; split("Red Green Blue",Colors[1]) }`.

Answer (score 14):

You can create a 2-dimensional array easily enough.  What you can't do, AFAIK, is initialize it in a single operation.  As [dmckee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2509/dmckee) hints in a comment, one of the reasons for not being able to initialize an array is that there is no restriction on the types of the subscripts, and hence no requirement that they are pure numeric.  You can do multiple assignments as in the script below.  The subscripts are formally separated by an obscure character designated by the variable SUBSEP, with default value 034 (U+001C, FILE SEPARATOR).  Clearly, if one of the indexes contains this character, confusion will follow (but when was the last time you used that character in a string?).

```
BEGIN {
    Colours[1,1] = "Red"
    Colours[1,2] = "Green"
    Colours[1,3] = "Blue"
    Colours[2,1] = "Yellow"
    Colours[2,2] = "Cyan"
    Colours[2,3] = "Purple"
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            printf "Colours[%d,%d] = %s\n", i, j, Colours[i,j];
}
```

Example run:

```
$ awk -f so14063783.awk /dev/null
Colours[1,1] = Red
Colours[1,2] = Green
Colours[1,3] = Blue
Colours[2,1] = Yellow
Colours[2,2] = Cyan
Colours[2,3] = Purple
$
```

Answer (score 8):

<sup>The existing answers are helpful and together cover all aspects, but I thought I'd give a more focused summary.</sup>

The question conflates two aspects:

- initializing arrays in Awk in general
- doing so to fill a *two-dimensional* array in particular

#### Array initialization:

Awk has ***no* array literal (initializer) syntax.**

The simplest **workaround** is to:

- represent the array elements as a *single string* and
- use the `split()` function to split that string into the elements of an array.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { n=split("Red Green Blue", arr); for (i=1;i<=n;++i) print arr[i] }'
Red
Green
Blue
```

<sup>This is what the OP did in [their own helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064269/45375).</sup>

If the elements themselves contain whitespace, use a custom separator that's not part of the data, `|` in this example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { n=split("Red (1)|Green (2)", arr, "|"); for (i=1;i<=n;++i) print arr[i] }'
Red (1)
Green (2)
```

---

#### Initialization of a 2-dimensional array:

- **Per POSIX**, Awk has **no *true* multi-dimensional arrays, only an *emulation*** of it using a *one*-dimensional array whose indices are implicitly concatenated with the value of built-in variable `SUBSEP` to form a *single key* (index; note that *all* Awk arrays are *associative*).

  - `arr[1, 2]` is effectively the same as `arr[1 SUBSEP 2]`, where `1 SUBSEP 2` is a *string concatenation* that builds the key value.
  - Because there aren't truly multiple dimensions - only a flat array of compound keys - you cannot enumerate the (pseudo-)dimensions individually with `for (i in ...)`, such as to get all sub-indices for primary (pseudo-)dimension `1` only.
  - The default value of `SUBSEP` is the ["INFORMATION SEPARATOR ONE" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm), a a rarely used control character that's unlikely to appear in date; in ASCII and UTF-8 it is represented as single byte `0x1f`; if needed, you change the value.
- By contrast, ***GNU* Awk**, as a nonstandard extension, *does* have support for **true multi-dimensional arrays**.

  - **Important**: You must then always specify the indices *separately*; e.g., instead of `arr[1,2]` you must use `arr[1][2]`.

**POSIX-compliant example** (similar to [TrueY's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147087/45375)):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  n=split("Red Green Blue", arrAux); for (i in arrAux) Colors[1,i] = arrAux[i]
  n=split("Yellow Cyan Purple", arrAux); for (i in arrAux) Colors[2,i] = arrAux[i]
  print Colors[1,2]
  print "---"
  # Enumerate all [2,*] values - see comments below.
  for (i in Colors) { if (index(i, 2 SUBSEP)==1) print Colors[i] }
}'
Green
---
Yellow
Cyan
Purple
```

Note that the emulation of multi-dimensional arrays with a one-dimensional array using compound keys has the following **inconvenient implications**:

- Auxiliary array `auxArr` is needed, because you cannot directly populate a given (pseudo-)dimension of an array.
- You cannot enumerate just *one* (pseudo-)dimension with `for (i in ...)`, you can only enumerate *all* indices, across (pseudo-)dimensions.

  - `for (i in Colors) { if (index(i, 2 SUBSEP)==1) print Colors[i] }`
     above shows how to work around that by enumerating *all* keys and then matching only the ones whose first constituent index is `2`, which means that the key value must start with `2`, followed by `SUBSEP`.

***GNU* Awk example** (similar to [Steve's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064658/45375), improved with [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) comment):

GNU Awk's (nonstandard) support for true multi-dimensional arrays **makes the inconveniences of the POSIX-compliant solution (mostly) go away**
(GNU Awk also doesn't have array initializers, however):

```
gawk 'BEGIN {
  Colors[1][""]; split("Red Green Blue", Colors[1])
  Colors[2][""]; split("Yellow Cyan Purple", Colors[2])
  # NOTE: Always use *separate* indices: [1][2] instead of [1,2]
  print Colors[1][2]
  print "---"
  # Enumerate all [2][*] values
  for (i in Colors[2]) print Colors[2][i]
}'
```

Note:

- **Important**: As stated, to address a specific element in a multi-dimensional array, always use *separate* indices; e.g., `[1][2]` rather than `[1,2]`.

  - If you use `[1,2]` you'll get the standard POSIX-mandated behavior, and you'll mistakenly *create* a new, single index (key) with (string-concatenated) value `1 SUBSEP 2`.
- `split()` can conveniently be used to directly populate a sub-array.
- As a prerequisite, however, the 2-dimensional target arrays must be initialized:

  - `Colors[1][""]` and `Colors[2][""]` do just that.
  - Dummy index `[""]` is just there to create a 2-dimensional array; it is discarded when `split()` fills that dimension later.
- Enumerating a specific dimension with `for (i in ...)` is supported:

  - `for (i in Colors[2]) ...` conveniently enumerates only the sub-indices of `Colors[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

A similar solution. `SUBSEP=":"` is not really needed, just set to any visible char for demo:

```
awk 'BEGIN{SUBSEP=":"
split("Red Green Blue",a); for(i in a) Colors[1,i]=a[i];
split("Yellow Cyan Purple",a); for(i in a) Colors[2,i]=a[i];
for(i in Colors) print i" => "Colors[i];}'
```

Or a little bit more cryptic version:

```
awk 'BEGIN{SUBSEP=":"
split("Red Green Blue Yellow Cyan Purple",a); 
for(i in a) Colors[int((i-1)/3)+1,(i-1)%3+1]=a[i];
for(i in Colors) print i" => "Colors[i];}'
```

Output:

```
1:1 => Red
1:2 => Green
1:3 => Blue
2:1 => Yellow
2:2 => Cyan
2:3 => Purple
```