# AWK array initialization

Tags: arrays, awk

Is it possible to initializate an array in AWK with the common *list* syntax?

```
array = [val1, val2, val3]
```

Or is it obligatory to use the *index-value* syntax?

```
array[0] = val1
array[1] = val2
array[2] = val3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array of arrays in awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063783/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-arrays-in-awk)

Answer (score 8):

No and no. This is how you do it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("val1 val2 val3",array); for (i in array) print i, array[i]}'
1 val1
2 val2
3 val3
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programing, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as if you don't know this then there's a lot of other awk basics you're missing too.