# Loop through files in a directory and select rows based on column value using awk for large files

Tags: awk

I have 15 text files (each about 1.5 - 2 GB) in a folder, each with about 300,000 to 500,000 rows and about 250 columns, each with a header row with column names. I also have a list of five values ("a123", "b234", "c345", "d456", and "e567"). (These are arbitrary values and the values are not in order and they do not have any relation with each other)

For each of the five values, I would like to query in each of 15 text files and select the rows if "COL_ABC" or "COL_DEF" equals the value. ("COL_ABC" and "COL_DEF" are arbitrary names and the column names do not have any relation with each other.) I do not know which column number is "COL_ABC" or "COL_DEF". They differ between each file because each file has a different number of columns, but "COL_ABC"/"COL_DEF" would be named "COL_ABC"/"COL_DEF" in each of the files. Additionally, some of the files have both "COL_ABC" and "COL_DEF" but others have only "COL_ABC". If only "COL_ABC" exists, I would like to do the query on "COL_ABC" but if both exists, I would like to do the query on both columns (i.e. check if "a123" is present in other "COL_ABC" or "COL_DEF" and select the row if true).

I'm very new to awk, so forgive me if this is a simple question. I am able to only do simple filtering such as:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ if(($1 == "1") && ($2 == "2")) { print } }' file1.txt
```

For each of the fifteen files, I would like to print the results to a new file.

Typically I could do this in R but my files are too big to be read into R. Thank you!

Comment: That's really not as bad as you think. Each file will be processed in sequence, and since each file contains a header row, simply use `'FNR == 1 { ...; next }` for the condition on your rule to read the 1st record in each file. Loop over each field, `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { col[$i] = i }` to index the `col` array by the column NAME with the field no. as the value. Then for the rest of the records you can loop `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ("name_you_want" in col) { # do what you want with $i value }`. You can swap `col[i] = $i` if you need to preserve column order.

Comment: [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- The input filenames have the form as "*.txt".
- The columns are separated by a tab character.
- Each of five values are compared with the target column (COL_ABC or COL_DEF) one by one and individual
  result files are created according to the value. Then 15 x 5 = 75 files will be created. (If this is not what you want, please let me know.)

Then would you please try:

```
awk -F"\t" '
    BEGIN {
        values["a123"]                                  # assign values
        values["b234"]
        values["c345"]
        values["d456"]
        values["e567"]
    }
    FNR==1 {                                            # header line
        for (i in values) {                             # loop over values
            if (outfile[i] != "") close(outfile[i])     # close previous file
            outfile[i] = "result_" i "_" FILENAME       # filename to create
            print > outfile[i]                          # print the header
        }
        abc = def = 0                                   # reset the indexes
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                     # loop over the column names
            if ($i == "COL_ABC") abc = i                # "COL_ABC" is found: assign abc to the index
            else if ($i == "COL_DEF") def = i           # "COL_DEF" is found: assign def to the index
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for (i in values) {
            if (abc > 0 && $abc == i || def > 0 && $def == i)
                print > outfile[i]                      # abc_th column or def_th column matches i
        }
    }
' *.txt
```

If your 15 text files are located in the directory, e.g. `/path/to/the/dir/` and you want to specify the directory as an argument, change the `*.txt` in the last line to `/path/to/the/dir/*.txt`.

Comment: IMHO, OP didn't ask for output files(if I read it correctly) so may be you could add another solution which only prints lines(since OP's data is huge it may save few cycles)? Just a thought, thanks for sharing good answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for the thoughtful comment. As the OP says: `For each of the fifteen files, I would like to print the results to a new file`, I had thought of generating individual files. It may be too much. I'd like to wait for the OP's feedback. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you are right @tshiono making files like your shown code will be better, this is good approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My actual values are more like "a123", "f456", d679", etc. where they are not in order and also include letters instead of "1", "2", "3", "4", "5". Would you be able to update your answer to reflect that? I will edit my question. And yes, I would like to print results to new files.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly (by just modifying the BEGIN block). Would you please test it? BR.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code worked :) However, I realized my original question is a bit different than what I would like. I updated my question to say ```If only "COL_ABC" exists, I would like to do the query on "COL_ABC" but if both exists, I would like to do the query on both columns (i.e. check if "a123" is present in other "COL_ABC" or "COL_DEF" and select the row if true). ``` Originally it was ```If only "COL_ABC" exists, I would like to do the query on "COL_ABC" but if both exists, I would like to do the query on "COL_DEF"``` Would you be able to update your answer?

Comment: Thank you for testing my script. Let me confirm my understanding for the case both
"COL_ABC" and "COL_DEF" exist. If the assigned value is "a123", print the row *if
 either "COL_ABC" or "COL_DEF" equals to "a123"*, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the assumption above. Hope it will meet your requirements. BR.

Comment: Yes, it did, thank you. If I wanted to add more columns to check, do I just add another line such as ```else if ($i == "COL_GHI") def = i``` in the second for loop and ```ghi > 0 && $ghi == i``` in the third for loop? Also would you be able to let me know how to run the file if I copy and paste the code into a text editor? I'm unsure how to pass in the entire directory containing the files as an argument. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Your assumption about adding more columns to check is right.
For instance, if you want to add `COL_GHI`, introduce a variable `ghi` (the variable
name doesn't matter anyway), then reset to `0` as well as `abc` and `def`, and add the
statements as you commented above.
Let me confirm the second question. Do you want to pass a directory to the awk script
other than the current directory?

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Yes, I would like to add the current directory.

Comment: I've added a comment about the location of the files at the end of my answer. Am I answering your question? BR.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in file*.txt; do
    awk -F'\t' '
        BEGIN {
            n1="COL_DEF"
            n2="COL_ABC"

            val["a123"] 
            val["b234"] 
            val["c345"] 
            val["d456"] 
            val["e567"] 
        }
        NR==1 {
            for(i=1; i<=NR; i++)
                col[$i]=i
            c=col[n1]
            if(!c) c=col[n2]
            next
        }
        $c in val { print }
    ' "$f" > "$f.new"
done
```

- we don't really need to set `n1`, `n2` (we could use the string values directly) but it keeps all definitions in one place
- awk doesn't have a very nice way to declare all elements of an entire array at once, so we set `val` elements individually (alternatively, for simple values [we could use `split`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318352/awk-array-initialization))
- on the first line of the file (`NR==1`), we store the header names, then immediately look up the ones we care about and store the index in `c` : we choose the first of `col[n2]` or `col[n1]` that is defined (non-zero) to be the column index to be searched
- `next` skips the remaining awk actions for this line
- then for every remaining line we check if the value in the relevant column is one of the values in `val` and, if so, print that line.

The awk script is enclosed in a bash `for` loop and we write output to a new file based on the loop variable. (This could all be done in awk itself, but this way is easy enough.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I replace ```file*.txt``` in the first line with just ```*.txt``` because my file names don't start with file. I am just copying and pasting your code into my terminal after I ```cd``` into the directory with all the files. However, the new files I get are all zero bytes unfortunately. They shouldn't be because just loading one of the files into R and running my query gives me results.

Comment: "I am just copying and pasting" is not a good idea for random code you get from the internet. I see you changed your question after I wrote this answer. Hopefully it is obvious that you could have replaced "1" with "a123" and so on, yourself?

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to replace "1" with "a123" myself. Just wanted to mention, I modified my question a bit so your answer may be different now. (Please see my most recent comment for the other answer. Thank you!)