# Need to simplify updating file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script that tests if servers are up and running, and if down write how long in a log file
Script works fine, but I like it to do less writing to speed it up.
As it is now, it write the complete log file for every server it test.
It may be possible to store information in some variable or array, then writ once.

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUS="/usr/local/server.info"
LOG="/var/log/servers_up_log"

# What server to monitor
SRV=(SR1 SR2 SR3)

# Test if log file exists, if not create it.
if [[ ! -f "$LOG" ]]; then
    >"$LOG"
fi      

for UC in ${SRV[*]}; do

    # Test if server is already in log, if not add it.
    if ! grep -q $UC "$LOG" ; then
        echo "$UC|0" >> "$LOG"
    fi

    isup=$(awk -F\| '$1==test {if ($2~/connected/) print "1"; else print "0"}' test="$UC" "$STATUS")

    if [[ $isup = 1 ]]; then
        #if server is up, add "0" to log file
        awk -F\| '$1==test {$2=0}1' OFS=\| test="$UC" "$LOG" > tmp && mv tmp "$LOG"
        else
        #if server is down for first time update log file
        if [[ $(awk -F\| '$1==test {print ($2==0?0:1)}' test="$UC" "$LOG") = 0 ]]; then
            awk -F\| '$1==test {$2=date}1' OFS=\| test="$UC" date="$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")" "$LOG" > tmp && mv tmp "$LOG"
        fi

    fi

done
```

`STATUS` is the file that holds information about the serves.
`LOG` is the file where it writes the status and it looks like this:

```
SR1|0
SR2|2014/05/12 20:25:05
SR3|0
```

If its `0` its up and running. The date show when it went down

`SRV` array is not like this, its a dynamic number of servers read form a file.
I just added three server to see how it looks like for the program.

---

So the program does like this.:
Test if `LOG` file exists, if not create an empty one.

Then for every server in `SRV`:
See if its in the `LOG` file, if not, add it with a `0`, server up.
Then see in the `STATUS` file if it has connected or not

If its connected, set the flag for server in `LOG` file to `0`,
If its not connected, set the flag for server in `LOG` file to a date,
but only if its `0` before, to prevent date from being renewed.

As you see in the `awk` part:

```
$1==test {$2=0}1
```

It writes the whole `LOG` file for every server, so with many server it will write many times to the `LOG` file. And not only one time for every run of script.

Comment: Could you give some sample of your current undesired input and indicate which lines should not appear? It is not very clear to me what you mean with "it will write many times to the LOG file".

Comment: @fedorqui If you have 100 servers, it will write the `LOG` file 100 times fore every times script is run, not one, that I like it too do. It may be better to store the whole update in an array, then write array out when all server is tested.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is this: from within the `for` loop, remove *all* redirections so each command writes to stdout. Then, redirect the whole `for` loop with

```
for UC in ${SRV[*]}; do
:
done >> "$LOG"
```

Voila, the log file is only opened once.

Additionally, I wouldn't worry about **re**-writing the log file from inside the loop. I'd just write all data, then filter out the lines you don't want. You'll need to provide details for that filtering.

Comment: It would be an idea.  Problem that this is part of a munin script, and there are already echo within the lines that get the standard out.

Answer (score 0):

Using ideas from [use-array-variable-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400304/715769). I am only showing the parts of your script that I have modified:

```
if [[ $isup = 1 ]]; then
    #if server is up, add "0" to log file
    #awk -F\| '$1==test {$2=0}1' OFS=\| test="$UC" "$LOG" > tmp && mv tmp "$LOG"
    keys+=($UC); values+=(0)  # storing the server name and the value to be stored in arrays
else
    #if server is down for first time update log file
    if [[ $(awk -F\| '$1==test {print ($2==0?0:1)}' test="$UC" "$LOG") = 0 ]]; then
        #awk -F\| '$1==test {$2=date}1' OFS=\| test="$UC" date="$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")" "$LOG" > tmp && mv tmp "$LOG"
        keys+=($UC); values+=(1) 
    fi
fi
```

And then after the for loop, add this awk command:

```
awk -v ks="${keys[*]}" -v vs="${values[*]}" -v date="$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")" '
    BEGIN{ split(ks, keys, / /); split(vs, values, / /);
    FS="|"; OFS="|"; }
    {
        for (i in keys) {
            if(keys[i] == $1) { $2 = values[i]; break; }
        };
        if ($2 == 1) { $2 = date }
    }
    1
' $LOG > tmp && mv tmp $LOG
```

So, we create two arrays `keys` and `values`. `keys` stores the servernames and `values` store the value we want to write against those servers. In the awk command at the end, we create awk arrays from our bash arrays. See [use-array-variable-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5400304/715769) for some explanation.

One problem here is that `values` cannot have spaces and our date format has one space. I have used a simple "1" to indicate that this value needs to be a date and then substituted with the date value in the new awk command.

The for loop inside the awk just goes through the `keys` array and if the servername from this array matches `$1`, it uses the current index to find the corresponding value from the `values` array. Also, if the value is "1", we use the date value.

Comment: a comment about style: within a quoted string (i.e. the awk script body), you don't need all those line continuations. They are just clutter

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. That's good to know. Have removed them now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like this:

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%Y/%m/%d %T")" -v srv="${SRV[@]}" '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="|"
    split(srv,srvArr,/ /)
}
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i in srvArr; i++) {
        if ($1 == srvArr[i]) {
            prevStatus[i] = $2
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1; i in srvArr; i++) {
        if ($1 == srvArr[i]) {
            currStatus[i] = $2
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i in srvArr; i++) {
        # Test prev and curr status arrays and print
        # whatever you need to for each combination.
        prev = prevStatus[i]
        curr = currStatus[i]
        if (prev == "") {
            if (curr == "") {
            }
            else if (curr == "connected") {
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        else if (prev == "connected") {
           etc...
        }
    }
}
' "$LOG" "$STATUS" > tmp && mv tmp "$LOG"
```

Change "connected" to 1 if/when appropriate. Use the date variable when necessary. If you need to append to the log file instead of overwriting it, append tmp instead of mv-ing it, etc.