# awk dynamic field list to print

Tags: bash, awk

what is the best way to do something like

```
awk '{ print $1, $3, $5 }'
```

but in a dynamic way?

The case is that the last field to print in only known at runtime.
so it might be $1, $3, $5,   it might also be $1, $3, $5, $7, $9 or even more

my first trial is like:

```
awk -v MAX=7 '{for (i = 2; i < MAX; i+=2) {print i,$i} }'
```

but it print one field in a line:

```
a[2]
a[4]
a[6]
```

instead of

```
a[2] a[4] a[6]
```

is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for all your suggestion. :)

One follow-up question.
at runtime, I already have the sequence available, say MyArray=(2 4 6 8)
is there a way to "pass" this array into awk and ask awk to print $2 $4 $6 $8 ?
so that I can save one for-loop inside awk

Comment: You should avoid editing questions after they have been answered, and particularly to add new or different requirements. That makes it a *different* question, so just ask a new question. If you feel it is important, reference the original question in the new one. The reason: when answers are not related to the question, it is confusing for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  won't do that again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `printf` omits the newlines but you'll need to use a [format string](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html) and add a newline yourself:

```
awk -v MAX=7 '{
    for (i = 2; i < MAX; i+=2) {
        printf "a[%d]=%s " i, $i
    }
    printf "\n"
}'
```

Note that the above example includes a trailing space after the last `a[N]=VAL` on each line.  If you want to omit it, you can use something like:

```
awk -v MAX=7 '{
    print_num = 0

    for (i = 2; i < MAX; i+=2) {
        if ( print_num++ > 0 ) { printf " " }
        printf "a[%d]=%s" i, $i
    }
    printf "\n"
}'
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Llama.  This is definitely a good solution candidate.  There is one followup question that I just edited in.  wondering if there is a way to save this for-loop.  :)

Comment: I agree with @rici that your edit should probably be a separate question, but for your convenience that question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5400228/477563

Answer (score 0):

With an array A you can do

```
for i in $(seq 0 2 ${#A}); do
   printf "%s " ${A[i]}
done | sed 's/ $/\n/'
```