# File Name based on Array

Tags: arrays, variables, unix, awk

I have created an array:

```
declare -A months=( ["JAN"]="AP01" ["FEB"]="AP02" ["MAR"]="AP03" ["APR"]="AP04" ["MAY"]="AP05" ["JUN"]="AP06" ["JUL"]="AP07" ["AUG"]="AP08" ["SEP"]="AP09" ["OCT"]="AP10" ["NOV"]="AP11" ["DEC"]="AP12")
```

Now I want read the replaced value of the month as it splits the file and creates new file name:

```
awk -F, '{print "a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~",echo ${months["${"$3":0:3}"]}","~RM.txt"}' ExtractOriginal.txt
```

The field where the variable substitution occurs is column 3. In there I have `MAR-2016`, what I am expecting is a file named: `a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~MAR~RM.txt`. However, I get an error:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

What is the right syntax to take column 3, pass it to my array, return the Substitution variable and use it as the file name?

Comment: You are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use array variable in awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400228/use-array-variable-in-awk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways you could go about solving your problem. Which you choose is mostly contingent on how tied to `awk` you want to be.

#### Declare the array in `awk`:

Is there any reason for you not to declare the variable in `awk`?

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{months["JAN"]="AP01"; months["FEB"]="AP02"; months["MAR"]="AP03"; months["APR"]="AP04"; months["MAY"]="AP05"; months["JUN"]="AP06"; months["JUL"]="AP07"; months["AUG"]="AP08"; months["SEP"]="AP09"; months["OCT"]="AP10"; months["NOV"]="AP11"; months["DEC"]="AP12"}{print "a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~"months[substr($3,0,3)]"~RM.txt"}' ExtractOriginal.txt
```

(also note that I removed the commas from `print`, since those will add spaces that your question seems to indicate you do not want in the result)

As @Ed Morton pointed out, due to the nature of your array, we can simplify it's creation with `split`/`sprintf`, giving you this:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{split("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC",t," "); for (i in t) months[t[i]]=sprintf("AP%02d",i)}{print "a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~"months[substr($3,0,3)]"~RM.txt"}' ExtractOriginal.txt
```

#### Parse the variable into `awk`:

This seems closest to what you were trying to do in your attempt. This keeps the array available in `bash`, but handles getting the filename you want with `awk`. Since there is no native way to handle a `bash` array in `awk`, you have to construct the latter from the former (which is made more difficult by this being an associative array).

I did this by first changing the `bash` array into a more easily parsed string which I then passed into `awk` as a variable.

```
# Declare the array
declare -A months=( ["JAN"]="AP01" ["FEB"]="AP02" ["MAR"]="AP03" ["APR"]="AP04" ["MAY"]="AP05" ["JUN"]="AP06" ["JUL"]="AP07" ["AUG"]="AP08" ["SEP"]="AP09" ["OCT"]="AP10" ["NOV"]="AP11" ["DEC"]="AP12")

# Change the array into a string more easily parsed with awk
# Each element in this array is of the format MON=APON
mon=`for key in ${!months[@]}; do echo ${key}'='${months[${key}]}; done`

# See below explanation
awk -F, -v mon="$mon" 'BEGIN {split(mon,tmp," "); for(m in tmp){i = index(tmp[m], "="); months[substr(tmp[m], 1, i-1)] = substr(tmp[m], i+1)}} {print "a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~"months[substr($3,0,3)]"~RM.txt"}' ExtractOriginal.txt
```

Below is a more readable version of the `awk` script. Note that `-v mon="$mon"` passes the `bash` variable `mon` into `awk` as a variable also named `mon`:

```
 BEGIN {
  split(mon,tmp," ");            # split the string mon into an array named tmp
  for(m in tmp) {                # for element in tmp
    i = index(tmp[m], "=");      # get the index of the '='
    months[substr(tmp[m], 1, i-1)] = substr(tmp[m], i+1)                           
                      # split the elements of tmp at the '='
                      # and add them into an associative array called months
                      # the value is the part which follows the '='
    } 
} 
{
  print "a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~"months[substr($3,0,3)]"~RM.txt"
}
```

#### Skip `awk` entirely:

Another option is to simply not use `awk` at all, which removes the burden of getting the array into a workable state. It's not clear by your question if this is a potential solution for you, but personally I found this `bash` version much simpler to write/read/understand.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename="ExtractOriginal.txt"

declare -A months=( ["JAN"]="AP01" ["FEB"]="AP02" ["MAR"]="AP03" ["APR"]="AP04" ["MAY"]="AP05" ["JUN"]="AP06" ["JUL"]="AP07" ["AUG"]="AP08" ["SEP"]="AP09" ["OCT"]="AP10" ["NOV"]="AP11" ["DEC"]="AP12")

while read line; do                              # for line in file
    month_yr=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f3`        # get the third column
    month=${months[${month_yr:0:3}]}             # get first 3 characters
    echo 'a~ST_SAP_FILE~Actual~'$month'~RM.txt'
done <"$filename"
```

Comment: Instead of `months["JAN"]="AP01"; months["FEB"]="AP02"; months["MAR"]="AP03"` you can do `split("JAN FEB MAR",t); for (i in t) months[t[i]]=sprintf("AP%02d",i)` to make specifying the month to value mapping a bit less tedious and error-prone (e.g.mis-spelling "months" in an assignment).

Comment: @SnoringFrog This is pretty awesome, so I got the naming convention to work with your answer, I failed to mentioned that I had to split the file in multiple instances based on that same column 3 ,which contains for example MAR-15 in different rows I want all MAR-15 in the same file not multiple files. Thank you for your help, as I get used to this I hope to get better not only at coding but at asking questions.

Comment: My new code looks like this:      <i> awk -F, 'BEGIN{months["JAN"]="AP01"; months["FEB"]="AP02"; months["MAR"]="AP03"; months["APR"]="AP04"; months["MAY"]="AP05"; months["JUN"]="AP06"; months["JUL"]="AP07"; months["AUG"]="AP08"; months["SEP"]="AP09"; months["OCT"]="AP10"; months["NOV"]="AP11"; months["DEC"]="AP12"}{print > $3 "a~ST_SAP_FILE_Actual~"months[substr($3,0,3)]"-20" substr($3,5,2)"~RM.txt"}' ExtractOriginal.txt<i>     This however appends the Field 3 Name to the file.

Comment: @RaulR It's unclear what content you are trying to get into what file.

Comment: ok, So I just realized my mistake. I had to keep the Print command and the greater sign before the string. Once again Thank you very much @SnoringFrog